# Несоответствие типов в VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
b = Text1.Text
m = Text2.Text
i = Text3.Text
q = Text4.Text
n = Text5.Text
Do While q1 <> q
h = h + 0.01
w = (b + m * h) * h
X = b + 2 * h * Sqr(1 + m ^ 2)
r = w / X
If r > 0.1 And r < 1 Then Y = 1.5 * Sqr(n)
If r > 1 And r < 3 Then Y = 1.3 * Sqr(n)
c = (1 / n) * (r ^ Y)
q1 = w * c * Sqr(r * i)
Loop
End Sub
```

ошибку дает при вычислении "с". На отладке задаю b=m=i=1, q=50, n=0.025
если кто знает почему, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- У вас в **8-ой** строчке кода:

  h = h + 0.01

задается переменная **h** которая равна **самой себе** + **0.01**, но вычислить это невозможно тк значение h нигде не задано. И дальше вычисления идут неверно в силу того что всё подвязано на этой вашей неизветстно откуда берущейся **h** ;)

- Ах да, и в **7-ой** строчке кода цикл **while** сравнивает переменные **q1** и **q** он также не выполняется тк переменная **q1** тоже не задана изначально.
- Ну если быть уж достаточно откровенным: в **12** и **13** строчке идет расчет **Y**

  If r > 0.1 And r < 1 Then Y = 1.5 * Sqr(n)

  If r > 1 And r < 3 Then Y = 1.3 * Sqr(n)

и может так получится что не одно условие не совпало и переменная **Y** также не будет задана.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Пойду отлаживать дальше.